# PyQT5 QTreeView. Как поймать событие

Tags: python, pyqt

QStandardItem есть свойство setEditable если оно True то можно редактировать. Необходимо поймать событие завершения редактирования.

Answer (score 0):

Покурил [доку](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#itemChanged) и вопрос решил так:

```
class Tree(QTreeView):
   def __init__(self):
       QTreeView.__init__(self)
       self.model = QStandardItemModel()
       self.setModel(self.model)
       self.model.itemChanged.connect(self.event_edit)
    ...

    def event_edit(self):
        pass
```